# login authentication with jquery modal form

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

What I want to do is when some one enters Name , Email , Password and Hit Button *Create an Account*.

It should go to mysql database and check if Name, Email, Password is present . If it is present then it should allow the person, if not then it should give a error invalid NAME OR Password. How would I implement this?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: What code have you tried? We aren't monkeys, it would be nice if you'd even made an attempt...

Comment: That's not generally the expected question format on StackOverflow. Usually you would post what you've tried so far (with code sample) and ask for help in resolving a specific problem. What you've asked is something that you should refer to a tutorial(s) for

Answer (score 0):

It is nice to validate the data both at the client and at the server level.
I would suggest not relying on validation of form data with javascript alone!

Please post what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to give some kind of helpful 'answer' to this I'm going to point you in the direction of this walkthrough:

http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/11/04/use-jquery-to-submit-form/

Of course that's assuming you're using PHP as a server side language for this.